# How to configure GCC to show all warnings by default?

Tags: linux, gcc, gcc-warning

I think it will be good and not much bad if `-Wall` flag is switched on by default. How do I configure GCC like this?

Is there any drawbacks to this other than the fact that a lot of warnings will flood your terminal when you are compiling some large program from source?

Comment: Why not just put it in the makefile?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can configure GCC with -Wall always on, but you could make a simple wrapper script that always invokes the real gcc with -Wall and forwards the other arguments.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because I being a student is compiling only single file programs w/o using makefiles.

Comment: Well, when I was a student I used makefiles also for single file programs.

Comment: @juzzlin So did you copy/rewrite the makefile whenever you wrote a program? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Traditionally, you set the *compile* options in `CFLAGS` and *link* options in `LDFLAGS` which are made part of your compile string either through use of `make` or by inclusion on the command line.

Comment: You could add -Wall to the specs file, but that's more complicated than a wrapper.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Can I know why it's so complicated? Or did you mean that it is not recommended?

Comment: It isn't very complicated, my comment was more about how trivial a wrapper would be (and once you get used to writing wrappers, you'll find tons of applications for them). Also, you didn't specify if you want to use a precompiled gcc or patch and compile a new version.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, thanks! Infact I already wrote one for gcc, put it in my /usr/bin and i like it. I will post it as an answer and maybe you can review it?

Comment: @daltonfury42: there are many benefits to always using a `Makefile`. If you always write tests on your code, you'll notice you find a lot of errors and you produce much better code. In the Makefile, you can have the `all` target always build and run tests. It ensures you don't break anything when doing a change.

Comment: @ColinPitrat It would be very nice if you could give an example makefile as an answer?

Comment: @daltonfury42: Done with details on my way of doing things. As I'm quite off-topic, I hope it won't bring me tons of down-votes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines to your ~/.bashrc if you use bash as your shell.

`alias gcc='gcc -Wall'`

Update:

you can refer to this question on https://superuser.com/questions/519692/alias-gcc-gcc-fpermissive-or-modifying-configure-script

If you use make, you need to overwrite make's variables CC and CXX from within the .bashrc:

`export CC="gcc -wall"
export CXX="g++ -wall"`

Comment: Thanks. This would be the proper answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

juzzlin suggested that a good method would be to write a wrapper for gcc.  Marc Glisse also suggested that writing one is the best way to achieve what I want. So that's just what I did.

I made a bash script that calls gcc for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Compiling $1..."



gcc -Wall -Werror -o $(basename $1 .c).out $1

a=$?

if [[ "$a" -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Failed!"

else 
    echo "Done." 
    echo "Executing:"
    ./$(basename $1 .c).out
fi
```

Then I copied the script to `/usr/bin` and made it executable:

```
sudo cp car /usr/bin
chmod +x /usr/bin/car
```

(The name of the script is `car` which stands for "Compile And Run")
So whenever I want to compile a source file and run it, I will type:

```
car mysourcefile.c
```

Comment: I was thinking of simply `#!/bin/sh exec gcc -Wall "$@"` (changing line before `exec`), but that's the beauty of scripts, if you like it the way you wrote it, then that's how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments (although it's not a direct answer to your question), using a Makefile has many benefits. It provides a place where to put your build commands, that will alway stay up to date if you only build with `make`. It also ease running tests at each build.

[Writing tests is a good habit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), even when you're just working on a small and unsignificant piece of code for homeworks. It allows you to spot some dumb mistakes that you would otherwise miss, and to be sure you don't break your existing code by modifying it (especially the last minute modification).

An [example](https://github.com/ColinPitrat/polynomial/blob/master/src/polynomial/Makefile) of such a Makefile (here I have nothing to build apart from the test because it's a header only component):

```
all:
    g++ -O2 -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 test_polynomial.cc -o test_polynomial -lgmp
    g++ -O2 -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 test_g2polynomial.cc -o test_g2polynomial
    ./test_polynomial --log_level=test_suite
    ./test_g2polynomial --log_level=test_suite

clean:
    rm -f test_polynomial test_g2polynomial
```

Note: The example is not a very good one as I don't even factorize the build options in `CFLAGS`. If I want to add a flag, I have to add it in both commands !

Another benefit is that you always run `make` to build, whatever the language, the dependencies or even the build system (when working on a project using scons or another build system, I still write a Makefile doing all the commands I do when building and testing !).

This allows my personal addition on it (but here we're completely off-topic): I have a build script named [`autobuild`](https://github.com/ColinPitrat/myconfig/blob/master/bin/autobuild) looping on make [each time I write a file in vim](https://github.com/ColinPitrat/myconfig/blob/master/.vimrc#L30). I code in screen and run `autobuild` in a [small window at the bottom of my screen](https://github.com/ColinPitrat/myconfig/blob/master/.screenrc#L16). This way, each change is built and tested as soon as I write the file.